# Как сдвинуть текст? Listview OwnerDraw

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Добавил иконки, но как теперь сдвинуть текст? Чтобы стало нормально.
Добавление иконки:

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, 24, 24);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[e.Item.ImageIndex], rectangle);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как я понимаю, метод `Graphics.DrawImage` просто рисует изображение в заданном месте. При этом это рисование не влияет на то, что у Вас там уже есть. Если хотите иконки побольше - можно задавать их размер в `ImageList` через `imageList.ImageSize = new Size(24,24);` Если задавать изображения во время добавления `ListViewItem` в `listView1.Items`, то не придется ничего двигать. Вот так: `listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0/*индекс изображения из ImageList*/, Text = "Notepad++" });` и тогда `OwnerDraw` будет `false`. Можно и пробелов в начало строки `Process Name` добавить )))

Comment: У меня OwnerDraw = true; Задумывался тоже о вставке пробелов но лучше как то отрисовать. Но как не знаю

Comment: а Вам `OwnerDraw = true` обязательно? Если нет, то мой вариант Вам идеально подойдет )

Comment: Добавь отдельный столбец для иконки